# calling a specific function to do a task inside React onClick Callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am trying to do a specific task whenever an item is called. But this is compromising DRY principal so I tried to finish the work by using a function and got a React error! then tried to do it with CustomHooks but got the same error!! is there any way to avoid code code repetition

> React Hook "useDeleteInventory" cannot be called inside a callback.
> React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom
> React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

callback function

```
onClick={() =>   useDeleteInventory(
                                item._id,
                                myInventories,
                                setMyInventories
                            )
                        }
```

CustomHook -

```
import axios from "axios";

const useDeleteInventory = async (id, inventories, setInventories) => {
const url = `http://localhost:5000/inventories/${id}`;
const proceed = window.confirm("Are you sure?");
if (proceed) {
    await axios.delete(url);

    const remainingInventories = inventories.filter(
        (inventory) => inventory._id !== id
    );
    setInventories(remainingInventories);

}
}
 export default useDeleteInventory
```

Comment: Is there a reason why it must be a custom hook? Why not just make it a function and import it when need in your component.

Comment: gives a pretty similar error,

Comment: gives a similar error about hooks?  can you give a more detailed error. Cause you should no longer get error regarding hooks. He hook error is because you are assigning a hook to onclick.